# Angular16 Issue with MatSelectionList Can't set a value

Tags: angular, angular-material

The project is using angular16, This is the code sample

```html
    <mat-selection-list
        [multiple]="false"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of mylist" [value]="item">
            {{ item }}
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

```
    mylist = ['elementA', 'elementB', 'elementC']

    selectedItem = 'elementB';
```

I got the following error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: values.forEach is not a function
TypeError: values.forEach is not a function
    at MatSelectionList._setOptionsFromValues (list.mjs:1032:16)
    at MatSelectionList.writeValue (list.mjs:983:18)
    at onChange (forms.mjs:3111:27)
    at forms.mjs:3586:50
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.setValue (forms.mjs:3586:28)
    at forms.mjs:4063:26
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:27450:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at zone.js:1264:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
```

I can't really see the problem, any suggestion please ?

Comment: I see the problem. the `selectedItem`should be an array of values !

Comment: selectedItemshould = ['elementB']

Answer (score 0):

The property connected to the list's `ngModel` should be an array type.  So, you just need to change `selectedItem` to an array.

```
protected mylist = ['elementA', 'elementB', 'elementC'];

protected selectedItems = ['elementA'];
```

Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/9daxye?file=src%2Fexample%2Flist-single-selection-example.ts